# How Can I put data into the table in Laravel API?

Tags: laravel, model, controller

I have a database that was given to me, and I need to build an API on it
but the columns in the table don't have a `created_at` or `updated_at` column. Every time I put code into the runtime it gives me this error.

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'updated_at' in 'field list'

Comment: add public $timestamps = false; in your model to ignore the update and create files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set timestamps to false for example:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set public $timestamps to false in your model, and also remove it from your **database migration**

remove this line
`$table->timestamps();`

or

appendix to
`$table->timestamps()->nullable();`

whichever suits you the best. If you think you'll change your mind later, you could set it to nullable.